# how to get value in ajax which is use inside the typeahead using asp.net mvc.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When we use array value directly. it is working fine. How to get the values from the database and store in array. inside `typeahead` we are using ajax to get the `brandname` and `productid` from the database but it is not working. we require when we click on text box we need to display list of values from the database.

```
$('#txtMedicineName').typeahead({
                minLength: 0,
                maxItem: 5,
                order: "asc",
                hint: true,
                accent: true,
                searchOnFocus: true,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetBrandName")',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return item;
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Html:

```
<div class="typeahead-container">
                                    <div class="typeahead-field">
                                        <span class="typeahead-query">
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.MedicineName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtMedicineName", placeholder = "Medicine Name", name = "MedicineName", type = "search", autocomplete = "off" })
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetBrandName(string prefix)
        {
            ProductMasterContext master = new ProductMasterContext();
            var customers = (from customer in master.productMasters
                             where customer.BrandName.StartsWith(prefix)
                             select new
                             {
                                 label = customer.BrandName,
                                 val = customer.ProductID
                             }).ToList();

            return Json(customers);
```

[image: gggg]

if i pass the value `var BrandName= [ "hi","hello" ];`  it is working correctly. but we require how to get the value from the database.

```
$('#txtMedicineName').typeahead({
                minLength: 0,
                maxItem: 5,
                order: "asc",
                hint: true,
                accent: true,
                searchOnFocus: true,
                source: BrandName
            });
        });
```

[image: working]

Comment: Have you checked the resulting JSon from your $.ajax call? If so, can you paste an example?

Comment: @EmilioCeroleni  no sir . Any idea??

Comment: You could try with Postman or Fiddler.  Or you can temporarily allow GET for GetBrandName and try to get a result in your browser with something like: "yoururl/Prescription/PrescriptionManagement/GetBrandName?prefix=xx"

Comment: Another (not very best practice) option could be calling alert in 
response($.map(data, function (item) {
                              // alert(item); 
                               return item;
                            })